# I have different tables in database - I want to select table dynamically with user clicking

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have different tables in my database. I want to write a single query to handle all tables like:

```
comm.CommandText = "Select * from table1 where UserId='" + 1 + "'";
comm.CommandText = "Select * from table2 where UserId='" + 1 + "'";
```

It is same query but different table name.

Is there any possible way to write both query with one query?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at : **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.71%29.aspx**

Comment: do you want to run two queries at the same time and return the result in the same result set? so essentially get back data from both tables at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

try using this:

```
string query = string.Format("Select * from {0} where UserId={1}", tableName, userID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code - string.Format

```
var input = "table 1";
var query = string.Format("Select * from {0} where UserId= 1 ",input);
comm.CommandText = query;
```